# Simplifying expression for y

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm having trouble simplifying $x+x^{-1}-y=0$. I want it to simplify to $x=...$ some expression of $y$, but every time I do this I end up back at the original equation!

Am I missing a property of $x+x^{-1}$ that would simplify to a single term?

Answer (score 0):

Your equation is:
$$
x+\frac{1}{x}-y=0
$$
that, multiplying by $x\ne 0$, becomes:
$$
x^2-xy+1=0
$$
solving for $x$ we have:
$$
x=\frac{y\pm \sqrt{y^2-4}}{2}
$$

Comment: Oh okay, where $a=1$, $b=-y$ and $c=1$. Thank-you, I knew I was missing something.